# unicode icon for ascending and descending order

Tags: javascript, html, unicode

I have seen Unicode for alphabets symbols, and have used in many areas. Recently I have a new requirement to create a ascending and descending functionality for which within the button I need to but the icons for that, I have seen the Icons for the  ascending and descending in many areas, an example is shown in the picture

[image]

But couldn't find any Unicode character for that anywhere, I have tried to make a similar icon like the above with Unicode like as shown below, but not able to create like as shown in the above picture

```
<span>&#65;&#90;&#8595;</span>
```

AZ↓

Can anyone please tell me some solution for this, is there any Unicode or Icons image for that available in web

Comment: Use fontawesome http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/sort-alpha-asc/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just for the giggles :)

```css
.letter {
    font-size: 10px;
    float: left;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
.crimson {
    color : crimson;
}
.darkblue {
    color: darkblue;
}
.arrow {
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 10px;
}
.container {
    width: 10px;
    line-height: 9px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <span class="letter darkblue">A</span>
    <span class="letter crimson">Z</span>
</div>
<span class="arrow">&#8595;</span>

<div style="height: 30px;"></div>

<div class="container">
    <span class="letter crimson">Z</span>
    <span class="letter darkblue">A</span>
</div>
<span class="arrow">&#8595;<span>
```

Comment: @Ismali its working fine, but the arrow seens a little bit down

Answer (score 3):

Use fontawesome. They have this icon and are free. http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/sort-alpha-asc/

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use http://glyphicons.com/ , or http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/ especially if you need to use multiple icons in your project. They are vector based so they have the same quality even on scaling. Also you can control them with css(the font-size, color and background